Attaching Clothing to Character Mesh
I'm having an issue where this big jacket won't work with the character rig. I've tried many tutorials on data transferring or attaching clothing (usually for more skin tight clothing) but the mesh doesn't seem to cooperate and bugs out. Even joining the mesh to the character doesn't seem to work. Any solutions would be helpful. Thanks :)


Here is the link to the blend file:
https://mega.nz/file/oPcizDzR#0QwjQztpThrsIxyF8YBmpiWH982dpYz8YMJXzF5c5Vk

if you really want an answer for your special case, pls provide blend file so we know what you did, see all technical settings and can provide help for you. If you don't wanna do that, keep watching yt tutorials where this is explained and follow them along, don't just watch them, repeat what the tutor said in Blender. Then transfer that knowledge to your case.

I also recommend using the generated rig for animation and not the metarig. This is only a helper armature to adjust the bone layout. It's not used for animation (although you can use it to quickly create a pose)

First thing you have 2 layers in your vest, maybe you should delete the inner one to simplify your mesh, it will still need some works though:

Also if you put your armature in rest pose the sleeves don't follow the same shape, you'll need to correct that, for example in Sculpt mode with the Pose brush:

Once you've done that + clean your mesh a bit + maybe merge by distance so that the sleeves stick to the body of the vest, parent With Automatic Weights and it should work...

This was so helpful! Thanks!
